# How to root a function in a discrete-event simulation-AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I implement a discrete event simulation model namely "EOQ" in AnyLogic from https://www.runthemodel.com/models/2662/

I am going to optimize the parameters by minimizing total inventory cost. Therefore, I have to construct a function (one of the agent component in AnyLogic) in order to be able to root the total cost.

Currently, I have constructed a function and root the total cost (i.e. root.inventorycost()), but the total cost results in the same value whenever the parameters change.

is it possible to root the total cost when the model only has events, parameters, and variables? how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: you don't need a function just use the variable totalCost (assuming that you have one) and minimize that... so will use root.totalCost instead of the function you are using

Comment: I agree that a variable would work, but the example "Activity Based Costing Analysis" shows a function working, so I suspect there is something else going on with this model.  Try running a couple of simulation experiments with your parameters set to something that would be covered by the optimization.  Verify that you get different results at the simulation level.  If you do, then it is something wrong with your optimization setup.  Otherwise, there is an issue with the underlying model itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your feedback. By Rooting the variable totalCost, now the optimization gives an appropriate result, I got a different result with the different parameter change. It is solved.